# Two copies of a question

Tags: bug, exact-duplicates

There are two cases in the last hour of questions which have appeared twice, with both copies appearing pretty much simultaneously:

[313547](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313547/) = [313548](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313548/)

[313550](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313550/) = [313551](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313551/)

Coincidence or bug?

**EDIT:** I posted this question about 20 minutes ago and got an error message saying that it couldn't be posted (I don't remember the exact words). I didn't try again, but just noticed that my question has subsequently appeared. I'm guessing that the posters of the questions that I noticed on the main site *did* try again ...

Comment: Another one 313554 = 313555.

Comment: It seems that SO had the same issue today: [is there any issue in Stack Overflow question list today?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375674)

Comment: Also possibly related (same time frame): [Recent problems with searching (no results or getting maintenance page)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/317169)